# Split data JSON after data in VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

How to split data in JSON if have array after array? This is my JSON format

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "error": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "sections": [
                {
                    "section_id": 1,
                    "position": []
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

So, I'm using AXIOS . This code AXIOS

```
const url = '/api/v1/form/'
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    this.listing = response.data.data;
                })
```

How to call section using this `response.data.data.sections` ? I'm try but error undefined. Please help me thanks

Comment: well data is an array i doubt you can use it without indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.data.data[0].sections`

`data` is an array according to your json so you cannot directly call sections you will have to iterate or select an instance within the array.

the following code should print all section ids //untested code

```
const url = '/api/v1/form/'
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    response.data.data.foreach((listing)=>{
                        console.log(listing.sections.section_id)
                    })
                })
```

If you always will have only one entry under `data` or you want to access only the 1st entry of `data` you can use  `response.data.data[0].sections` this is a bad way to access it though because if data is empty it will throw you an error . If the case is that you only have one entry under `data` you should just change your json to be

```
{
"status": "true",
"error": "",
"data":
    {
        "id": 1,
        "sections": [
            {
                "section_id": 1,
                "position": []
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

and you can then access it directly `response.data.data.sections` but as long as its an array you will have to treat it as such.

Iterate through sections and positions [as per comments]:

```
 const url = '/api/v1/form/'
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    response.data.data.foreach((listing)=>{ //#this will get you each listing(parent object that contains sections array)
                        listing.sections.foreach((section)=>{//# this will get you each section(parent object that contains position array)
                           section.position.foreach((el)=>{//# this will get you each elment in the position array as `el`
                               console.log(el)
                           })
                        })

                    })
                })
```

Comment: how to write if looping for ```section``` and ```position```

Comment: for within for would work. you can do a lot of things but for loops are  `Array.foreach(function)`

Comment: I'm not understand, can explain more to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const url = '/api/v1/form/'
axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => {
        this.listing = response.data;
        console.log(this.listing.data) // <-------
    })
```

Comment: I know it, but how to call ```sections``` in data?